Have issue for rotate and crop using cropperjs
Here is my blade file.
@include('backend.inc.image_picker', [
                                        'label' => translate('Gallery Images'),
                                        'size' => '(600x600)',
                                        'dropzoneId' => 'gallery_images',
                                        'name' => 'gallery_images',
                                        'note' => translate('These images are visible in product details page gallery. Use 600x600 sizes images.')
                                    ])

@include('backend.inc.image_picker', [
                                        'label' => translate('Thumbnail Image'),
                                        'size' => '(300x300)',
                                        'dropzoneId' => 'thumbnail_image',
                                        'name' => 'thumbnail_image',
                                        'note' => translate('This image is visible in all product box. Use 300x300 sizes image. Keep some blank space around the main object of your image as we had to crop some edge in different devices to make it responsive.')
                                    ])

Below is my javascript code to initialize dropzone and handle other actions. It is placed in include file named as image_picker.blade.php
    <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">{{ $label }} <small>{{ $size }}</small></label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="dropzone" id="{{ $dropzoneId }}">
            <div class="dz-message">{{ translate('Drag and drop files here or click to upload.') }}</div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="{{ $name }}" class="selected-files">
        <small class="text-muted">{{ $note }}</small>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false; // Disable Dropzone auto-discovery

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#{{ $dropzoneId }}", {
                url: "/dummy-url", // Dummy URL for initialization
                autoProcessQueue: false,
                maxFilesize: 5, // MB
                acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                dictRemoveFile: '<i class="las la-trash-alt"></i>',
                init: function() {
                    var selectedFilesInput = document.querySelector(
                    'input[name="{{ $name }}"]');

                    this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function(e) {
                            var files = selectedFilesInput.value ? JSON.parse(
                                selectedFilesInput.value) : [];
                            files.push(e.target.result);
                            selectedFilesInput.value = JSON.stringify(files);

                            var image = file.previewElement.querySelector('img');
                            var buttonsContainer = document.createElement('div');
                            buttonsContainer.classList.add('buttons-container');

                            var rotateLeftBtn = document.createElement('button');
                            var rotateRightBtn = document.createElement('button');
                            var cropBtn = document.createElement('button');
                            var removeBtn = file.previewElement.querySelector('.dz-remove');

                            rotateLeftBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="las la-undo"></i>';
                            rotateRightBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="las la-redo"></i>';
                            cropBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="las la-crop"></i>';

                            rotateLeftBtn.classList.add('btn', 'btn-sm', 'btn-secondary',
                                'mr-2');
                            rotateRightBtn.classList.add('btn', 'btn-sm', 'btn-secondary',
                                'mr-2');
                            cropBtn.classList.add('btn', 'btn-sm', 'btn-secondary', 'mr-2');

                            buttonsContainer.appendChild(rotateLeftBtn);
                            buttonsContainer.appendChild(rotateRightBtn);
                            buttonsContainer.appendChild(cropBtn);
                            buttonsContainer.appendChild(removeBtn);
                            file.previewElement.appendChild(buttonsContainer);

                            var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
                                aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                                viewMode: 1,
                                autoCropArea: 1,
                                responsive: true,
                            });

                            console.log('Cropper initialized:', cropper);

                            rotateLeftBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                console.log('Rotate Left Button Clicked');
                                console.log('Cropper instance:', cropper);
                                cropper.rotate(-90);
                            });

                            rotateRightBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                console.log('Rotate Right Button Clicked');
                                console.log('Cropper instance:', cropper);
                                cropper.rotate(90);
                            });

                            cropBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                var croppedCanvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
                                var croppedDataUrl = croppedCanvas.toDataURL();

                                var files = selectedFilesInput.value ? JSON.parse(
                                    selectedFilesInput.value) : [];
                                files = files.map(f => f === e.target.result ?
                                    croppedDataUrl : f);
                                selectedFilesInput.value = JSON.stringify(files);

                                image.src = croppedDataUrl;
                                cropper.destroy();
                                cropper = new Cropper(image, {
                                    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                                    viewMode: 1,
                                    autoCropArea: 1,
                                    responsive: true,
                                });
                            });

                            this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
                                var files = selectedFilesInput.value ? JSON.parse(
                                    selectedFilesInput.value) : [];
                                files = files.filter(f => f !== file.dataURL);
                                selectedFilesInput.value = JSON.stringify(files);
                                cropper.destroy();
                            }.bind(this));
                        }.bind(this);
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    }.bind(this));
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

I want to uploaded/drag drop image that could be single image or multiple. Once image is uploaded user can rotate, zoom or crop the image.
Currently, drag & drop and remove image is working fine. having issue with rotate and crop.
Error when I hit rotate button:
cropper.min.js:10 Uncaught 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rotate')
    at i.rotate (cropper.min.js:10:24622)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (create:2161:41)

Error when Hit crop button
create:2172 Uncaught 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toDataURL')
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (create:2172:68)

